# Remove defrost vent for ford focus 2016 SE

Tags: ford, focus, vents, defroster

I have difficulties in removing front defrost vent grills [image: front defrost vent grills]for ford focus SE 2016 because some small gravel(stones) Slipped into it.

i tried to pull it but didn't work. i didn't find any clips or screws to unfasten.

can any one help me with that do i have to remove all dash? or is there another way to clean it?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Ugh.  Usually these are tabs in slots, then tip and snap in place.  Not sure of the orientation of the tabs for this model.  I will say, when sunlight UV rays (and excessive heat) degrades the plastic, these break / snap apart quite easily.  On older cars, before starting a job, best to check prices of OEM replacement grills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can find an image of the underside, it will probably show some plastic clips. Usually one can use a small screwdriver or plastic tool to lift the grille close to the clip locations.

You will probably find that the grit has descended down the tubes further than you envisage... It is a good idea to get them out before they get to the blower motor - if they can they will...